# How can AOSP git repository be so fast to clone?

Tags: git, android-source, gerrit, jgit

When i tried to host a private git server, i noticed that it's really fast to clone from Google repository

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base
Cloning into 'base'...
remote: Sending approximately 3.10 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 1225, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (153/153)
remote: Total 4235951 (delta 2851145), reused 4235884 (delta 2851145)
Receiving objects: 100% (4235951/4235951), 3.09 GiB | 34.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:  99% (2843979/2851145)
```

The first four output lines are nearly instant, less than 1 second. and `counting objects` only shows 1225

```
Cloning into 'base'...
remote: Sending approximately 3.10 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 1225, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (153/153)
```

However if i setup an exactly same repo on my local machine and try to `git clone`, the output like this

```
Cloning into 'base'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4231671, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4231671/4231671), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (788638/788638), done.
```

it takes about 1 minutes to couting and compress, and you can see 4m objects. How does google achieve this?

Comment: I guess the official repo is well-packed, i.e. very few (if any) lose objects and everything is packed into pack-files. See [git repack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack).

Comment: I don't think so. First the repo i tried to serve is exactly clone the from google and never modified. And there is only one pack file in objects/pack and no any other file. Besides i also tried to run `git gc --aggressive`, still cannot clone as fast as google

Comment: What git version are you serving it from? I know there's been massive improvements in there over the years. If the serving git version is old enough, that could slow you down. Oh: and more importantly: are you cloning directly from a file URL or are you cloning via a server (ssh or https)? Because a "DUMB" clone will behave very differently from one with an active agent on the remote side. Basically: can you share the git command you use for the local clone?

Comment: version is 2.25.1. and command is `git clone http://localhost/git/test/base.git` I delibrately setup an apache http server over git to simulate the behaviour of Google repository. BTW i think you can check if you can reproduct it

Answer (score 4):

These four messages:

> ```
> remote: Sending approximately 3.10 GiB ...
> remote: Counting objects: 1225, done
> remote: Finding sources: 100% (153/153)
> remote: Total 4235951 (delta 2851145), reused 4235884 (delta 2851145)
> ```

come from the other participant in your `git clone`, i.e., they come from `android.googlesource.com`.

If you examine the source code for Git, you will not find any `Sending approximately` message anywhere.  So these messages are not coming from *Git*.  They're coming from some other program that *acts like* Git.

So, the answer to:

> How does google achieve this?

is: "They don't use Git."  Or, more likely—though it amounts to the same thing in the end—they use a hacked version of Git that detects an initial clone and uses an optimized send path at this point.  I have often thought that Git should probably do this, at least as an option (the drawback to doing this is that you could leak internal-only, to-be-GC-ed objects that are not meant to be sent by clone; but if you have a dedicated source code distribution center, where you are sure to build "releasable" pack files, this would not be a problem).

Whether and how you could get Google's hacked version of Git—if my guess is right—is another question entirely, as is the question of whether you would *want* that version.

Comment: I *think* I remember that Android/GoogleSource uses/used gitolite at some point. But even if they don't, there's a good chance that what they are using is open source software.

Comment: @JoachimSauer. Actually i think you're right. I tried to find if google open sourced it but i didn't find it

Comment: I have a hard time locating the code that lets the aosp remote respond with "Sending approximately". I checked git itself, Eclipse's jgit, Gitiles and gitolite

Answer (score 2):

The infrastructure on `googlesource.com` is based on JGit and Gerrit.

You might want to try serving your repo with bitmaps (`git repack --write-bitmap-index`). Bitmaps speed up the processing necessary for serving Git data, and they are used on `googlesource.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shallow clone with `--depth` option. Ex:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base --depth=1
```